# Plotting a Simple Pendulum

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve, plot, and do other stuff with the simple pendulum equation; I'm well aware that NDSolve can handle stuff like this, but I'm looking for symbolic solutions:

```
DSolve[y''[t] + (g/l) Sin[y[t]] == 0, y[t], t]
```

Mathematica yields the following solutions. Are c[1] and c[2] the constants of integration? If so, which is which? That is, which one is y[0] and which one is y'[0]? Or do they mean something else?

```
{{y[t] -> 
   2 JacobiAmplitude[(Sqrt[2 g + l C[1]] (t + C[2]))/(2 Sqrt[l]), 
                     (4 g)/(2 g + l C[1])]}, 
 {y[t] -> 
  -2 JacobiAmplitude[(t Sqrt[2 g + l C[1]])/(2 Sqrt[l]) + (Sqrt[2 g + l C[1]] C[2])/(2 Sqrt[l]), 
                     (4 g)/(2 g + l C[1])]}}
```

But trying to plot with realistic values for $g$ and $l$ and choosing zeros for the presumed constants of integration (y'[0] = 0, y[0] = 0), I would expect a flat line for a pendulum that is not moving, but that isn't what comes out:

```
Plot[2 JacobiAmplitude[(Sqrt[2 g + l C[1]] (t + C[2]))/(2 Sqrt[l]), 
                       (4 g)/(2 g + l C[1])] 
                       /. 
                       {g -> 9.80665, l -> 0.9936, C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}, 
     {t, -8, 8}]
```

So what am I doing wrong here? And how would I get an expected sinusoidal curve for a pendulum that starts at an angle with zero velocity? Thanks

Comment: There is something not quite right in this solution. For example `ode=y''[t]+(g/L) Sin[y[t]]==0; DSolve[{ode,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0},y[t],t]` should give zero as solution, but now it does not solve it. The exact solution for the nonlinear pendulum is given in terms JaconiSN special function.  Here is a [reference](http://www.pgccphy.net/ref/nonlin-pendulum.pdf)  equation (10).  btw, this not a **simple** equation. [Papers](https://www.scielo.br/j/rbef/a/ns9Lc7tfqhZh678dBPXxRsQ/?format=pdf&lang=en)  were written on this. This is hard ode to solve. The linear version is much simpler ofcourse.

Comment: `C[1]` and `C[2]` are constants of integration, but they are arbitrary (it could very well be `C[1]/100` or `C[1]^100-34`, no?)  You just need to solve for `y[t]/.t->0` and `D[y[t],t]/.t->0`, but doing so is actually quite difficult.  Perhaps https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/ch4/solution.html is useful.

Comment: Using dimensional analysis you can check whether the constants are compatible with what you imagined. However, if dimensional analysis says that the dimensions are compatible, it does not say whether the constant are indeed y[0] or y'[0]. For example, in the first solution, the sub-expression  t + C[2] means that C[2] is a time reference and so it can not be y[0] or y'[0].